# WooCommerce REST API Updating Images issue

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a working product feed going through the REST API for WooCommerce, everything is perfect, except that when I re-import the feed, the image on the product gets replaced but I then get duplicate images in my Media Library and Uploads folder - now reaching 2gb as I didnt notice this until just now.

If there an easy way to force Wordpress to delete unused images on a regular basis, or a way to access the current image and delete it from the Media Library before importing the new one?

Thanks,

Answer (score 6):

Adding the ID in the images array will force it to overwrite, I was putting a 0 here if an image did not exist, which caused issues

Answer (score 0):

Passing the image IDs did not help in my case.

I'm using [wp_delete_attachment](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_delete_attachment/%20wp_delete_attachment()) to delete the images before updating.

```
if ($id) {
    $post = $woocommerce->get('products/'.$id);
    wp_delete_attachment($post['images'][0]['id'];);
}
```

Images array used for create/update batch process:

```
'images' => [
  [
    'src' => 'https://www.example.com/uploads/image/'.$product['image'],
    'title' => $product['name'],
    'alt' => $product['name'],
    'position' => 0
  ]
],
```